# Display Multidimensional array as list

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to display a multidimensioal array and I am doing that in a very static way. I wonder how I could achieve the same results with a foreach.

I've tried accessing individualy which works but the coding technique seems not acceptable.

Table

```
         array(
         "name" => "Bob",
        "occupation" => "employee",
         "salary" => 1500,
         "specialty" => "programmer"
         ),
         array(
         "name" => "Sally",
        "occupation" => "manager",
        "salary" => 2300,
         "specialty" => "human resources management"
         ),
        array(
         "name" => "Jane",
        "occupation" => "employee",
        "salary" => 800,
        "specialty" => "secretary"
         ),
     );
```

My function

```
function printTable($table){
        echo "<h2>Employee #1</h2>";
        echo $table[0]["name"];
        echo $table[0]["occupation"];
        echo $table[0]["salary"];
        echo $table[0]["specialty"];

        echo "<h2>Employee #2</h2>";
        echo $table[1]["name"];
        echo $table[1]["occupation"];
        echo $table[1]["salary"];
        echo $table[1]["specialty"];

        echo "<h2>Employee #3</h2>";
        echo $table[2]["name"];
        echo $table[2]["occupation"];
        echo $table[2]["salary"];
        echo $table[2]["specialty"];
    }
```

Desired result http://prntscr.com/n5jnnu

Comment: Select an answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @ΚυριάκοςΚολέτσας If you don't know what Marios means, here's a link to guide you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329

Answer (score 1):

Check this.You have 2D array so we need 2 for loops, and then we print the key values (name is key) and the values.Also i have added a counter to print the number of employees.

```
    $counter = 1;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($table as $val){
        echo "<h2>Employee #$counter</h2>";
        foreach($val as $key => $val1){
            echo "<li>$key: $val1 </li>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $counter++;
    }
    echo "</ul>"
```

Comment: `$num` is undefined

Comment: @Andreas fixed.

Comment: Not my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the keys and values available in your multidimensional array.

To calculate the employee number, add 1 to the index (first level keys).

By writing the `<h2>` element outside of the `<ul>` tag, you achieve the tabbed-in look of your posted screenshot.

Use css to style the font of your `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags.

Tested Code:

```
$array = [
    ["name" => "Bob", "occupation" => "employee", "salary" => 1500, "specialty" => "programmer"],
    ["name" => "Sally", "occupation" => "manager", "salary" => 2300, "specialty" => "human resources management"],
    ["name" => "Jane", "occupation" => "employee", "salary" => 800, "specialty" => "secretary"]
];

echo "<h1>Employees and managers</h1>";
foreach ($array as $index => $row) {
    echo "<h2>Employee #" , $index + 1 , "</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($row as $label => $value) {
            echo "<li>$label: $value</li>";
        }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Output:

[image]